# Eclipse IDE not displaying Android Project Menu on Windows Xp

Tags: android, cordova, windows-xp, adt, eclipse-kepler

I developing android mobile application using phonegap..For developing android  mobile application I used Eclipse IDE and I installed all required plugins.But when I open the new menu it does not displaying Android Project opting in sub menu.
[image]

I used this development tool 6 months back, but after formatting hard drive and new installation of Windows Xp, I did a fresh installation. This time, I am unable to get this menu of “Android Project”

I tried couple of times to install ADT plug-in, but could not see the Android Project menu which I got previously.

System Details:
OS:windows xp sp3
Eclipse Version: Kepler Service Release 2
ADT Version :23.2
Installed ADT using below URL:https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse
Phonegap V:2.7

Comment: click other at the bottom of the New menu then you'll be able to select android application project. Later on it should appear in the menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straight way you will get "Android Application Project" after clicking on "Project" or "Other" items.

But as you said you want to see "Android Application project", for that you can customize perspective for "New" menu by:

> Window > Customize Perspective > Menu Visibility > Expand 'File' >
>   Expand 'New' > Tick 'Android Application Project'